# Finding variables in Ui_Form based on substring

Tags: python, self, iterable

I have a Ui_Form from QtDesigner that contains variable names, such as:

```
self.ui.alphabetic_menu_QLabel_A
...
self.ui.alphabetic_menu_QLabel_Z
self.ui.label
...
self.ui.label_10
```

I see that the Ui_Form is not iterable.  Is there a good Python way to extract all instances into a list of the variable names containing a specified substring (e.g., alphabetic_menu_QLabel)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know QtDesigner, but if you are dealing with a python instance this can be done using the [dir()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) built-in method.

`dir(yourform.ui)` returns a list of all the attribute names. From your example, I think you should get something similar to: `['alphabetic_menu_QLabel_A', ..., 'alphabetic_menu_QLabel_Z', 'label', ..., 'label_10', ...]`.

Be careful because `dir()` returns other stuffs too. From the docs:

> the list contains the object’s attributes’ names, the names of its class’s attributes, and recursively of the attributes of its class’s base classes.

So you need to filter the list. If you are interested in attributes containing a given substring only, you can use a list comprehension.

```
mysubstr = 'alphabetic_menu_QLabel'
myattributes = [att for att in dir(yourform.ui) if mysubstr in att]
```